# remote connection in Qt

Tags: qt, tcp, network-programming

How can I set up a connection between two remote computers, where one will represent the server and the other the client. Using the QTcpSocket and QTcpServer classes and knowing the ip address of the server. Is it possible?

I have the following implementation of connecting the client to the server by ip and port. Everything works if I run client and server applications on my computer. But if I put the server on a remote computer, then the connection does not occur.

```
//code client
void connectToDevice(QString _ip, int _port)
    {
        if(socket.isOpen()){
            if(ip == _ip && port == _port){
                return;
            }
            socket.close();
        }
        ip = _ip;
        port = _port;
        socket.connectToHost(ip, port);
    }

//code server
void TCPServer::on_client_connecting()
{
    qDebug() << "a client connected to server";
    auto socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(clientDataReady()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(clientDisconnected()));
    socketList.append(socket);
    socket->write("Welcom to this Server");
    emit newClientConnected();
}
```

Comment: Most likely blocked by firewall, or just the server not having a public IP. Running server reachable from anywhere in the internet of today is a bit complicated,  unless you use some cloud platform (like Azure, AWS, GCP...) to run your server.

Comment: Does `ping` work? Can you get a `netcat` client-server connection to work? Do learn to use netcat or socat or equivalent tool, if you plan to learn network programming, internet should have plenty of tutorials...